# How to configure SSO for chatbot deployed on SharePoint Web site?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, chatbot

I am trying to configure SSO on the SharePoint website using Power Virtual Agent Chatbot. We are using Azure for Authentication and SSO.

I had posted for help to achieve this on the Power Virtual Agent Community. I got a response saying **"We did get this working by using HttpContextAccessor to get the logged in user name and passing this through under exchangeTokenAsync as loginHint; doing this worked."** But have no idea how to achieve this.

I am using the below code and I am able to get the current Login User Name and Email Id of the current SharePoint Website.

```html
<script>
     ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getCurrentUser, "sp.js");
          //getCurrentUser();
          var currentUser;

          function getCurrentUser() {
            console.log("Inside getCurrentUser");
            var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = ctx.get_web();
            currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
            ctx.load(currentUser);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFailure);
          }

          function onSuccess() {
            console.log("Get Title: " + currentUser.get_title()); // Domain\Account
            console.log("Get Email: " + currentUser.get_email());
            console.log("Get Name: " + currentUser.get_loginName());
          }

          function onFailure() {
            console.log(
              "Request failed" +
                args.get_message() +
                "\n" +
                args.get_stackTrace()
            );
          }

          function exchangeTokenAsync(resourceUri) {
            let user = clientApplication.getAccount();
            if (user) {
              console.log("User exist" + user);
              let requestObj = {
                scopes: [resourceUri],
                login_hint: currentUser.get_title(),
              };
              console.log("RequestObj: " + JSON.stringify(requestObj));
              return clientApplication
                .acquireTokenSilent(requestObj)
                .then(function (tokenResponse) {
                  console.log(
                    "ExchangeTokenAsync requestObj: " +
                      tokenResponse.accessToken
                  );
                  return tokenResponse.accessToken;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  console.log("ExchangeTokenAsync error: " + error);
                });
            } else {
              return Promise.resolve(null);
            }
          }
</script>
```

In the logs I see the below.

Inside getCurrentUser

Get Title: <--Login User Name-->

Get Email: <--Login User Email Id-->@<--org-name-->.com

Get Name: i:0#.f|membership|<--Login User Email Id-->@<--org-name-->.com

getOAuthCardResourceUri: api://fed35aaa-xxxx-yyyy-aae0-54a2573bbbbb/Canvas.PVA.SSO

KMT - user exist[object Object]

requestObj: {"scopes":["api://fed35aaa-xxxx-yyyy-aae0-54a2573bbbbb/Canvas.PVA.SSO"],"login_hint":"<--Login User Name-->"}

exchangeTokenAsync requestObj: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL......token number goes on

**Error 502 https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/9xbtVbIwi0D8O7T2da9GKP-f/activities**

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kSgy.png)

Can anyone please help me to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts) and [repo](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-bot-framework-sso)  that can help you for share point SSO. OAuth services to support user sign-in and SSO. Below is the sample for S2S and user auth.

[Bot-authentication](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) demonstrates how to integrate OAuth providers for user authenticated flows.